# RDBMS Event-Store: Ensure ordering (single threaded writer)

Tags: postgresql, rdbms, event-sourcing

Short description about the setup:

I'm trying to implement a "basic" event store/ event-sourcing application using a RDBMS (in my case Postgres). The events are general purpose events with only some basic fields like `eventtime`, `location`, `action`, formatted as XML. Due to this general structure, there is no way of partitioning them in a useful way. The events are captured via a Java Application, that validate the events and then store them in an events table. Each event will get an `uuid` and `recordtime` when it is captured.

In addition, there can be subscriptions to external applications, which should get all events matching a custom criteria. When a new matching event is captured, the event should be PUSHED to the subscriber. To ensure, that the subscriber does not miss any event, I'm currently forcing the capture process to be single threaded. When a new event comes in, a lock is set, the event gets a `recordtime` assigned to the current time and the event is finally inserted into the DB table (explicitly waiting for the commit). Then the lock is released. For a subscription which runs scheduled for example every 5 seconds, I track the `recordtime` of the last sent event, and execute a query for new events like `where recordtime > subscription_recordtime`. When the matching events are successfully pushed to the subscriber, the `subscription_recordtime` is set to the events max `recordtime`.

Everything is actually working but as you can imagine, a single threaded capture process, does not scale very well. Thus the main question is: How can I optimise this and allow for example multiple capture processes running in parallel?

I already thought about setting the `recordtime` in the DB itself on insert, but since the order of commits cannot be guaranteed (JVM pauses), I think I might loose events when two capture transactions are running nearly at the same time. When I understand the DB generated timestamp currectly, it will be set **before** the actual commit. Thus a transaction with a `recordtime` *t2* can already be visible to the subscription query, although another transaction with a `recordtime` *t1* (*t1* < *t2*), is still ongoing and so has not been committed. The `recordtime` for the subscription  will be set to *t2* and so the event from transaction 1 will be lost...

Is there a way to guarantee the order on a DB level, so that events are visible in the order they are captured/ committed? Every newly visible event must have a later timestamp then the event before (strictly monotonically increasing). I know about a full table lock, but I think, then I will have the same performance penalties as before.

Is it possible to set the *DB* to use a single threaded writer? Then each capture process would also be waiting for another write TX to finished, but on a DB level, which would be much better than a single instance/threaded capture application. Or can I use a different field/id for tracking the current state? Normal sequence ids will suffer from the same reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to guarantee the order on a DB level, so that events are visible in the order they are captured/ committed?

You should not be concerned with global ordering of events. Your events should contain a Version property. When writing events, you should always be inserting monotonically increasing Version numbers *for a given Aggregate/Stream ID*. That really is the only ordering that should matter when you are inserting. For Customer ABC, with events 1, 2, 3, and 4, you should only write event 5.

A database transaction can ensure the correct order within a stream using the rules above.

> For a subscription which runs scheduled for example every 5 seconds, I track the recordtime of the last sent event, and execute a query for new events like where recordtime > subscription_recordtime.

Reading events is a slightly different story. Firstly, you will likely have a serial column to uniquely identify events. That will give you ordering and allow you to determine if you have read all events. When you read events from the store, if you detect a gap in the sequence. This will happen if an insert was in flight when you read the latest events. In this case, simply re-read the data and see if the gap is gone. This requires your subscription to maintain it's position in the index. Alternatively or additionally, you can read events that are at least N milliseconds old where N is a threshold high enough to compensate for delays in transactions (e.g 500 or 1000).

Also, bear in mind that there are open source RDBMS event stores that you can either use or leverage in your process.

**Marten**: http://jasperfx.github.io/marten/documentation/events/

**SqlStreamStore**: https://github.com/SQLStreamStore/SQLStreamStore

Comment: As stated above, I don't really have an Aggregate/StreamID, just a series of events coming from different sources. Thus there has to be a global sequence. While this is possible, I think it would be performance limiting for multiple capture processes. The ID has to be checked on each insert. A prefetched batch of IDs could lead to larger gaps, which also be hard to handle/ detected when reading events.Would one "simple" reread be enough? The idea about an extra delta for querying by recordtime might be a solution, but be a constant query overhead..right? I'll check your references!

Comment: Also stumbled upon this http://www.varlena.com/GeneralBits/130.php to get a gapless sequence. Might also be a viable solution, but again, a bit limiting I guess. At least it would be a lock on the central DB level (single leader DB).